# Redirect BACK from cloud functions to Firebase Hosting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, firebase-hosting

So I have the following idea: in order to make my SPA SEO friendly, I want to check on the server side if it's a web crawler (based on the headers), and if it is, I want to render the page with Puppeeteer and return it. Otherwise, I want it to be served as a normal SPA application.

I am using Firebase Hosting and want to do it with Firebase Cloud Functions. The thing is that I don't know how to normally serve the built React files from Functions. Can I somehow redirect it back to the Firebase Hosting?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there something you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect from Cloud Functions to any other website (your firebase hosting), set a redirect header.

```
exports.cb = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`https://my-project.firebaseapp.com`);
});
```